# Radiobutton list select an Item on page Load

Tags: asp.net, radio-button, radiobuttonlist

I have a radiobuttonlist that i am populating on runtime with a datasource. Now what I want is to select the item that has text "Daily At" by default when page is loaded. How to achieve this?

Comment: Can you please show us your current code for this? Makes it easier to spot possible syntax errors

Comment: Code is the same as I copied and pasted there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach (ListItem item in RadioButtonList1.Items)
            {
                if (item.Text.Contains("Daily At"))
                {
                    item.Selected = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Set **SelectedValue** property.

```
if(!IsPostBack)
{
 ....
 RadioButtonList1.DataBind();
 RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue="Daily At";
}
```

You can use SelectedIndex property.

```
if(!IsPostBack)
    {
     ....
     RadioButtonList1.DataBind();
     RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex=1;
    }
```

Here is sample for your reference:

```
public class Data
    {
        public int No { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Code in Page_Load event

```
   if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            List<Data> list = new List<Data>()
            {
                 new Data() { Name="Test1", No=10},
                 new Data() { Name="Test2", No=20},
                 new Data() { Name="Test3", No=30}
            };

            RadioButtonList1.DataSource = list;
            RadioButtonList1.DataTextField = "Name";
            RadioButtonList1.DataValueField = "No";
            RadioButtonList1.DataBind();

            RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue = "30";
        }
```

Comment: EXCEPTION: `'RadioButtonList1' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items.
Parameter name: value`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {   
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {    
      RadioButtonList.DataBind();
      RadioButtonList.Items.FindByText("Daily At").Selected=true;
    }
 }
```